# Наложение 2d текстуры на 3d куб

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, 3d

Так делают с 3D сферами в основном, я про наложения такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли поступить аналогичным образом с кубом? Скажем, кубическую планетку из карты высот хочу создать. Подскажите как. Буду благодарен за ключевые слова для поиска информации.

Comment: О каком ЯП речь?

Comment: А какая разница? Нужен алгоритм наложения. (ЯП -- ЯзыкПрограммирования, верно?)

Comment: Опишите (и проиллюстрируйте), что такое "поступить аналогичным образом с кубом" в вашем понимании?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, с кубом так не получится сделать, потому что в нем все намного проще ввиду его геометрической правильности.

В сфере идет сужение изображения по краям(не только по полюсам) и растяжение по центру. В кубе при движении с видом сбоку все обстоит иначе: видны только 2 грани, а искажение происходит за счет сужения одной и расширения другой и, при пересечении ребром середины, наоборот.

Если Вы хотите реализовать это в изометрической проекции, то принцип будет заключаться в искажении трех видимых ромбов - условном вращении верхнего и пропорциональном изменении двух нижних.

Картинки для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]